# Failed to connect to a valid mail server in liferay

Tags: java, liferay-6

I implement a mail service which works fine with local machine(liferay 6.1 with tomcat).
But when I deploy mail service into server(liferay 6.1 with webSphere server on Linux machine ) It wont work

It gives error as

**[liferay/scheduler_dispatch-164][MailEngine:560]**
Failed to connect to a valid mail server. Please make sure one is properly configured. Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465

Please suggest any solution

Comment: Can you make sure server has proper access/configuration[port, host etc.] for smtp ?

Comment: server has same configuration which I done on my local machine